# Could not set ASP.NET Core 3.1 environment string within an xUnit Integration Test

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I'd like to setup integration test for my ASP.NET Core 3.1 using the code below and have not been able to get the environment string correctly and even with `UseEnvironment("integration-test")` method, I still end up with `null` when I call `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` from within the Startup class. I tried getting the environment string from `IWebHostEnvironment` but from there I get `"Development"`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Application test fixture to generate the test host.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TStartup">The type of the startup.</typeparam>
/// <seealso cref="WebApplicationFactory{TStartup}" />
public class AppTestFixture<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    where TStartup : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The configuration.
    /// </summary>
    private Action<IServiceCollection> _configuration;

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this as a way to override container registration for integration testing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configuration">The configuration.</param>
    public void ConfigureTestServices(Action<IServiceCollection> configuration)
    {
        this._configuration = configuration;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder" /> used to set up <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder" /> instance.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The default implementation of this method looks for a <c>public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)</c>
    /// method defined on the entry point of the assembly of <typeparamref name="TEntryPoint" /> and invokes it passing an empty string
    /// array as arguments.
    /// </remarks>
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("integration-test")
            .UseStartup<TStartup>();

        if (this._configuration != null)
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(this._configuration);
        }

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didnt it change to DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT in 3.1? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments#environments

Comment: Doesn't say anything that it's deprecated. `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` overrides `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`. Also, I have a .NET Core 3.1 project that has a similar setup and it works there. So I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Forgot to mention that `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")` also returns `null`.

Comment: @secretAgentB Did you ever find a solution for this? Getting the same issue in .net 6

Comment: @Bassie I have added an answer to this question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the Environment's static method and set the environment accordingly. Like what I did here on my .NET 6 microservice app

https://github.com/secret-agent-B/devkit-dotnet-core/blob/master/src/apps/core/sdk/test/Devkit.Test/AppTestFixture.cs